# Limit of $f(1-x^2)$: 3, 1, 4, or undefined?

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

[image]

A couple of days ago in AP Calculus, we had an assignment with this problem. Earlier today in class, we received our grades on the assignment... and everyone got this singular problem wrong. However... I don't think she was able to explain it all that well either.

For those who can't see the image for whatever reason, you have a quadratic function that terminates with a hole at $(1,3)$, a point at $(1,2)$, and then a  clearly different quadratic function that starts at $(1,4)$. The question is then:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(1-x^2) = ?
$$

with the answer choices of $1$,$2$,$3$,$4$, and $\varnothing$. everyone chose either $1$ ($\lim_{x\to 0} 1-x^2 = 1$), $2$ ($f(1) = 2$), or $\varnothing$ ($\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = \varnothing$). According to the assessment (which was not made by my teacher), the answer was 3.

The way my teacher explained it seems pretty absurd. I don't remember much of it, but she said you had to adjust the values for the functions by flipping it across the x-axis, shifting it up 1, and then finding $lim_{x\to0}$. Most of us are super confused, and since I have an account for this community, I pretty much got nominated to ask for a solution from people significantly more experienced than us.

Send us help on this, please.

Comment: Have you drawn the graph of $f(1-x^2)$?

Comment: @Servaes No, the piecewise function is not given.

Comment: Clever problem.  In fact, the two one sided limits are both equal to $3$, since, as $x$ approaches $0$ (from either side) $x^2$ approaches $0$ from the right, hence $1-x^2$ approaches $0$ from the left, so (from the graph) the limit is $3$.

Comment: @AlexanderDay You have the graph of $f(x)$ near $x=1$. From this you can draw the graph of $f(1-x^2)$ near $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $y=x^2$. Since $x^2\ge0$, if the limit is rewritten with $y$ then $0$ is approached from the right:
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(1-x^2)=\lim_{y\to0^+}f(1-y)$$
Then writing $z=1-y$, $z$ approaches $1$ from the left as the sign is flipped:
$$=\lim_{y\to1^-}f(y)=3$$

Comment: This was, in fact, my initial idea, but my teacher rejected it. I dunno how I should feel about this.

Answer (score 2):

When $x$ is close to $0$, $1-x^2$ is always **close to, but smaller than** $1$. Therefore, whatever function $g$ we have, we can say $$\lim_{x\to 0} g(1-x^2) = \lim_{y\nearrow1} g(y)$$
which means, in your question, the limit will be $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the answer is $3$, $1-x^2<0$ (unless $x=0$, but the value of your function at $0$ doesn't matter), and therefore$$\lim_{x\to0}f(1-x^2)=\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=3.$$

Comment: The only thing that irks me in the way the problem is posed is that $\lim_{x\to 0}$ is used to denote the limit on the neighbourhhoods of $0$ *excluding $0$*, while the same symbol may be legitimately used for the limit on the neighbourhoods of $0$ *including $0$* ... Subtle difference but it changes the limit from $3$ to "not defined"... Is it only me seeing an ambiguity here? (In other words, we know what $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-}$ mean, is there a better symbol such as $\lim_{x\to 0^\pm}$, or do people commonly confuse the two in the calculus courses?)

Comment: No, you are not the only person who sees that. But my personal experience tells me that it is a sure bet that, when a person writes about the limit of a function $f$ at a point, then the definition that that person uses is such that the value of $f$ at the point is irrelevant. As a personal note, I wrote *two* textbooks in which the value of $f$ at the point *does* matter.